# How to access next element in loop in VM

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, velocity

I need to access to next element in `foreach` to compare some value.

In JSP, I added some dummy element, and loop like this;

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size() - 1; i++) {
    MyClass element = list.get(i);
    MyClass nextElement = list.get(i+1);

    if(element.getSomeValue() > nextElement.getSomeValue())
        doSome();
        ...
```

But in VM I can't get the element by index as far as I know.
If there's some way to access to next element, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Velocity template (the .vm file) can access any Java object that's placed into the [Context](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#The_Context).  In your backing Java class or Velocity servlet, place your list into the context:

```
context.put("list", myList);
```

Then in your Velocity template you can reference it as `$list` and you can call methods on it by using `$list.get(i)`, etc.  Note that unlike JSP, you can't place pure Java code in a Velocity template, you must use [VTL](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Loops).

Comment: I understand `$list.get(i)` and `$list.get(i+1)`. But What about `for(int i=0; i<list.size() - 1; i++){}`?

Comment: Velocity doesn't have a "native" concept of a for loop, but you can rig up the equivalent with a `#foreach`.  Have a look at [this post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/turbine-user/200306.mbox/%3C3EFC0A90.3010007@nr.no%3E).